# The Greeks were right

Tags: society, religion

So somehow, the world's scientists find solid evidence that the Hellenic Gods are the true gods. It's them and them alone. Think Zeus, Hera, Hestia, etc. This evidence is unquestionable.

How would the people of our modern day world react?

I'm primarily looking for three things: the Catholic church's reaction to it, the reaction to books/movies that had the gods as characters (such as Percy Jackson), and the American government's reaction to it. Out of these, the church's reaction is most important to me.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84190/discussion-on-question-by-azaleagarden-the-greeks-were-right).

Answer (score 7):

## Oh dear, we are in so much trouble.

You have to remember that the Greek gods aren't gods as we currently tend to think of them in the context of the Christian tradition. I say currently, the old testament still has a fair amount of blood and thunder. Spare the thunderbolts and spoil the congregation as they say. The Greek gods were forces of nature personified. You didn't ask them for boons, you made offerings in the hope that they wouldn't sink your ships.

You made offerings so that if they noticed you they didn't turn you into a turkey so they could have sex with your wife. Or turn you into a turkey because you caught sight of one of them bathing. Or just because it seemed funny. (Swans more common than turkeys)

## The church will react by going cluck

Greek gods have personalities, and most problematically, a sense of humour. Luckily for the complexities of the question, the chances of discovering this little problem by any means other than the Vatican burning to the ground and all the cardinals being turned into a new variety of red hen are slim.

Comment: *Some* Greek divinities can be seen as personification of the forces of nature. Some of them, including some of the most interesting of them, cannot. And people absolutely did pray (and offer gifts or sacrifices) to (some of) them in the hope of obtaining favor.

Comment: @AlexP the most interesting ones to me are forces of society personified, but that's a similar concept.

Comment: I really, really like your summary of the greek mythology. People get turned to turkeys and the gods fuck something or someone. 99% of Zeus myths are summed up by: "He couldn't keep it in his pants", after all.

Comment: I was going to argue that Zeus wouldn't be particularly interested in the RCC, but then i remembered [Ganymede](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ganymede_(mythology))

Answer (score 4):

If the OP is correct and the Hellenistic Pantheon truly exist, then the question isn't how the Church will react, but how *they* will react to being displaced from their proper position in the cosmos.

The [Olympian Gods](https://infogalactic.com/info/Twelve_Olympians) are in fact the third generation of supernatural beings to rule the Universe, the first being [Gaia](https://infogalactic.com/info/Gaia_(mythology)) and [Uranus](https://infogalactic.com/info/Uranus_(mythology)), and the second generation being the [Titans](https://infogalactic.com/info/Titan_(mythology)). The Olympian Gods fought a massive war (the [Titanomachy](https://infogalactic.com/info/Titanomachy)) for control of the Universe, and enlisted monstrous beings like the [Hekatonkheires](https://infogalactic.com/info/Hekatonkheires) and [Cyclopes](https://infogalactic.com/info/Cyclops) to aid them. The Olympians are not beings to be trifled with.

The attributes of the various members of the Pantheon also mean they can affect human society in a multitude of ways. Some of them are personifications of nature, while others are personifications of human traits and behaviours (amplified to a massive level). While [Aeolus](https://infogalactic.com/info/Aeolus) can blast the world with massive winds, or [Poseidon](https://infogalactic.com/info/Poseidon) stir the oceans and make the ground shake, [Athena](https://infogalactic.com/info/Athena), Goddess of Wisdom and Strategy can bestow her favour on people who are clever and cunning to advance the cause of the Olympians, [Aphrodite](https://infogalactic.com/info/Aphrodite) can use the power of sexuality to control or unhinged people, and [Ares](https://infogalactic.com/info/Ares), God of Battle, can inspire people to berserk rage either to support the Pantheon, or to disrupt the opponents of the Pantheon.

And of course [Zeus](https://infogalactic.com/info/Zeus), God of the sky, lightning, thunder, law, order, justice and King of the Universe, is unlikely to be pleased that after returning from a short vacation, the Pantheon is forgotten and people worship other deities. A thunderbolt in the right places will remind humans of their proper place in the Cosmos, and things had better get back in their proper order right away.

No, the Hellenistic Pantheon were a very "hands on" group of ruling deities, and if they were to return, they would take very active steps to set things back to the order *they* are accustomed to.

Comment: +1. Minor nitpicks: I'd prefer "Hellenic" to "Hellenistic"; the latter would imply Isis, Osiris, Seth and other Egyptian and Middle Eastern deities which would make Zeus look like an innocent lamb. And the Hellenic Gods *are*, rather than *were*; they are immortal, aren't they?

Answer (score 2):

I think the Church denies it, and so does anybody that believes in the Abrahamic God. Just think of the modern political tactics against, say, Global Warming (which they renamed Climate Change); that is what they will use.

No matter how "incontrovertible" your "evidence", it will be ridiculed, called "Fake News", endlessly questioned by people that sneer at it, including people in authority. Science doesn't matter. Facts do not matter.

The American Government's reaction will be in line with that (just like with Global Warming, which is scientifically incontrovertible). Either they ridicule it and flatly claim it is wrong, or they simply ignore it and take the high road, "The Constitution guarantees Freedom of Religion, so people are free to believe as they wish." In America, politicians have to be elected, and they almost universally give lip service to the religion of their constituents, because there is no point in alienating them and getting booted out of office. Most are smart enough that they don't feel any necessity to express their ***true*** beliefs, or even vote their true beliefs, because they want the job, the power, and the money they can derive from power. The truth will find no traction in the halls of American power until acknowledging the truth seems an electoral necessity to them.

Comment: We support debate and healthy discussion but take it easy with the insults everyone.  World building comments are not the ideal place to discuss worldview and complex concepts.  All in all:  [Be nice](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/conduct)

Comment: Just to clarify, I flagged and requested the deletion of insulting comments.

Answer (score 1):

In the comments, the original poster states that the evidence "should be" "strong enough to convince the Vatican's scientists".  The Vatican has some very smart, very devout scientists.  They are good at understanding theory, observing reality, and explaining how the one relates to the other.

Thus, I stipulate that highest levels of the Catholic Church will accept the revised cosmology.

In the early days of Christianity, Christian missionaries convinced Greeks that Christianity was true.  They asked the Greeks to consider the possibility that their beliefs in the Greek gods were consistent with the existence of a Creator, and further argued that their beliefs implied the existence of a Creator.

I expect that the Catholic church would revisit this logic, in order to find ways in which Catholic doctrine is consistent with the scientific evidence.  In particular, they would focus on the New Testament books in which the apostles communicated with Greek communities.